# In HTML forms does the label target the name or the id of the input?

Tags: html, forms, label

I've had this simple confusion for so long because in all the examples I've seen, the 'for' attributes value in the label tag matches both the 'id' tag and the 'name' tag of the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute `for` in a label, target the `id` of an input.

Some definitions:

```
<input>
```

> ***name:*** Name of the input form control. Submitted with the form as part
>   of a name/value pair.
>
> ***id:*** Global attribute valid for all elements, including all the input
>   types, it defines a unique identifier (ID) which must be unique in the
>   whole document. Its purpose is to identify the element when linking.
>   The value is used as the value of the `<label>`'s for attribute to
>   link the label with the form control.

```
<label>
```

> ***for:*** The id of a labelable form-related element in the same document
>   as the `<label>` element. The first element in the document with an id
>   matching the value of the for attribute is the labeled control for
>   this label element, if it is a labelable element. If it is not
>   labelable then the for attribute has no effect. If there are other
>   elements which also match the id value, later in the document, they
>   are not considered.

More information: [input element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) and [label element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)

Answer (score 0):

It targets the id.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp

> Specifies the id of the form element the label should be bound to